# How can I connect my DAPP to Metamask, if Coinbase Wallet injects another Ethereum provider?

Tags: web3js, ethereum-wallet-dapp

I am facing the following issue when trying to connect my DApp to Metamask:

Normally, Metamask injects ethereum provider authomatically and we just call Web3(window.ethereum) to instantiate the library.

Now, my problem is that having also installed Coinbase Wallet as a browser extension, it seems it is injecting also an ethereum provider, and now I have 2 providers and the selected one by default seem to be the Coinbase one. When I console.log window.ethereum, I am getting the folowing:

```
window ethereum 
 u {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 0, _maxListeners: undefined, providers: Array(2), 
  selectedProvider: w, …}
  enable: ƒ ()
  overrideIsMetaMask: true
  providers: (2) [w, Proxy]
  request: ƒ ()
  selectedProvider: w {_events: {…}, _eventsCount: 4, _maxListeners: undefined, 
  _filterPolyfill: e.FilterPolyfill, _subscriptionManager: e.SubscriptionManager, …}
  send: ƒ ()
  sendAsync: ƒ ()
  _events: {}
  _eventsCount: 0
  _maxListeners: undefined
  chainId: (...)
  isMetaMask: (...)
  networkVersion: (...)
  [[Prototype]]: o
```

As you can see, as selectedProvider I am getting w, while actually Metamask is the other one.
In the end, what I am trying to achieve is creating one button to connect to Metamask and another to connect to Coinbase Wallet, but even using web3-react, both buttons are connecting to Coinbase Wallet.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your case you need to get specific provider in window.ethereum:

```
const metamaskProvider = window.ethereum.providers.find((provider) => provider.isMetaMask);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me on the chrome as `window.ethereum.providers` is `undefined`. Any other solution?

Answer (score 0):

In order to provide for both **MetaMask ONLY** consumers and **Coinbase/MetaMask** consumers (where both extensions are installed), you must do a check if there is a providers array on the `window.ethereum` object to see if the array exists, and base your logic on this.  I typically write a selector method that's something like:

```js
/**
 * Returns an injected provider
 * @param walletType 'isMetaMask' | 'isCoinbaseWallet'
 * @returns Provider
 */
export function provider(walletType) {
  if (!window.ethereum) { throw new Error("No injected ethereum object."); }
  return Array.isArray(window.ethereum.providers)
    ? window.ethereum.providers.find((provider) => provider[walletType])
    : window.ethereum;
}
```

Then you could just do `provider('isMetaMask')` or `provider('isCoinbaseWallet')` depending on what you need.

It's a strange pattern, and I wish they would make the provider object structure more normalized to reduce conditional logic.